# Python UDF for piglatin script not finding re module

Tags: python, regex, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I'm having trouble creating a UDF for a piglatin script I'm using. My problem is that when I run the script with `pig script.pig` I get the following error:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1121: Python Error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    import re
ImportError: No module named re
```

And on my "utils.py" script, I'm importing the module like so: `import re`

Why is it not finding the `re` module and how can I fix it?

**Edit**
I should note that if I run the python script directly using the `python` command, I don't get an error saying that it couldn't find the  `re` module.

**Edit 2**

Ok, based on the comments, I installed jython (which wasn't installed on my system) and here are the outputs of `print sys.path` for my script:

*Using python*

```
['/home/hduser/bqmScripts/betsScripts', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages']
```

*Using Jython*

```
['', '/usr/share/jython/Lib', '/usr/lib/site-python', '__classpath__']
```

*Using pig*

```
['/pig/lib/Lib', '__classpath__', '__pyclasspath__/']
```

After seeing this, I tried to add the missing path elements from jython into the pig version, and what I get now is this:

```
 File "utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/share/jython/Lib/re.py", line 7, in <module>
    import sre, sys
  File "/usr/share/jython/Lib/sre.py", line 97, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/share/jython/Lib/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
AssertionError: SRE module mismatch
```

**SOLVED**

To solve my latest error message I looked for the version of jython that my pig installation was using (2.5) and installed that one manually. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re` is part of the stdlib, therefore either your Python installation is broken or incomplete, or something has damaged the contents of `sys.path`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "damaged the contents of sys.path" but if I run the script manually using the `python` command, I don't get the error msg.

Comment: then have your script print `sys.path` and compare the output when you use `python` and when you use `pig`.

Comment: `Pig` uses Jython to execute the UDFs, not CPython, which is why it would work in one and not the other.

Comment: Agreed Ignacio and I think you are right that this is his problem; I was pointing out that "it works when I type python" is a false lead. Try to see if it works when you use "jython" instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I edited my original post to reflect the changes.. still having issues though...

Comment: The new error is because `pig` is using a different version of Jython than is installed. Try putting the Jython path elements before the others.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No use, still the same error message. Any other ideas?